# What does the notation $S^n$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, notation

I see this notation a lot, but I can't seem to find an answer in my google searches. In particular I am looking at the question

> Let $\alpha:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ be the antipodal map. Prove that $n$ is odd, then $\alpha\simeq \operatorname{id}.$

If it is an arbitrary symmetric group, then I understand, but I have seen $S^1$ be used for the circle.

Comment: The antipodal map is the map $(x_1,.....,x_n)\to (-x_1,.....-x_n)$.  If $n $ is odd, like a circle, or a four dimensional sphere you can simply rotate the $S^n $ 180 degrees.  If $n $ is even, like the sphere in 3 space you can't.  In fact no matter what continuous map you map the points of a sphere in odd space, you'll always have a fixed point.

Comment: If the homotopy must be $H:S^n\times [0,1]\rightarrow S^n$, I don't see how a continuous map can't be made for even n... The problem doesn't ask me to say anything for even, but I would like to understand why. I have found the mapping $H(\textbf{x},t)=\textbf{x}-2t\textbf{x}$ to work as a homotopy for both

Answer (score 8):

The notation $S^{n}$ denotes the unit $n$-sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. That is, $$S^{n}=\left\lbrace(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n+1})\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\::\:\sum_{j=1}^{n+1}x_{j}^{2}=1\right\rbrace.$$

Answer (score 6):

The notation $S^n$ denotes the locally [$n$-dimensional unit sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere). For example $S^2$ is your classic sphere cut out in $(x,y,z)$-space by the equation $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$S^n=\{(x_1,x_2, \dots,x_{n+1}):  x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_{n+1}^2=1\}$$ is the n-dimensional unit sphere... in $n+1$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb E^{n+1}$...

It can also be considered independent of the surrounding space as an abstract *manifold* ...