# What is the meaning of $S^1$ or $S^2$?

Tags: general-topology, notation, soft-question

So I'm just getting into topology and I see spaces such as $S^1$ or $S^2$  used a lot.

What is the meaning of $S^1$ or $S^2$? Furthermore, what is  meant by the cartesian product $S^1 \times S^1$ or $S^2 \times S^2$?

I've looked everywhere and it's a difficult question to Google.

All I know is that it has to do with circles. Like a two-dimensional torus is composed of two circles and a three dimensional torus is composed of three circles.

I know this website is for higher-order, computational/proof-based questions but I don't know where else to go to find this information

Comment: $S^n$ means the [$n$-dimensional sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere).

Comment: I wouldn't say this site is (only) for "higher-order, computational/proof-based questions". This is a good place to ask.

Comment: I googled "S^n topology" and the first result was the Wikipedia page!

Comment: How are you trying to learn topology? Any good textbook or set of lecture notes should define standard terminology, like $S^n$.

Comment: ... in fact, such a good place to ask that it's been asked before: [What does the notation $S^n$ mean?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2656293/what-does-the-notation-sn-mean)

Answer (score 3):

In general, $\mathbb{S}^n$ denotes the $n$-dimensional unit sphere, i.e, the set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with magnitude $1$:

$$\mathbb{S}^n = \{v \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \ \vert \ \|v\| = 1 \}$$

And so we have:

$$\mathbb{S}^n \times \mathbb{S}^m = \{(v, w) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+m+2} \ \vert \ v \in \mathbb{S}^n, w \in \mathbb{S}^m \}$$

And the topology of these sets is the standard one, i.e the subspace topology.

Comment: What is the metric used on $\mathbb{S}^1$?